# If $\rho \approx_{\varepsilon}\sigma$, how to find $\Pi\rho\Pi$ to ensure that $\text{supp}(\Pi\rho\Pi)\subset\text{supp}(\sigma)$?

Tags: quantum-state, projection-operator, trace-distance

Let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be positive semidefinite operators with trace less than or equal to 1. Let $\rho\approx_{\varepsilon}\sigma$ i.e. they are close in some distance, such as the trace distance.

Assume that we have $\text{supp}(\rho)\not\subset\text{supp}(\sigma)$ i.e. there exists some vector $v$ such that $v^\dagger\rho v > 0$ but $v^\dagger\sigma v = 0$. It seems like I should be able to apply some projector to $\rho$ to obtain $\rho' = \Pi\rho\Pi$ where

1. $\rho'\approx_{\varepsilon}\rho$
2. $\text{supp}(\rho')\subset\text{supp}(\sigma)$

The intuition is that there are only some at most $\varepsilon-$small eigenvalues that I need to remove from $\rho$ to get it into the support of $\sigma$. Can someone help with how to construct such a projector?

Comment: Why don't you just take $\Pi$ as the projector onto the support of $\sigma$?

Comment: Oh! Yeah, good point - sorry for brainfart moment!

Comment: Thank you @MateusAraújo

Comment: @lolwut You could write your own answer!